# In WPF 4.0, switching tabs resets usercontrol UI

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, tabcontrol

I have a border that contains a TabControl in a HeaderedContentControl:

```
<Border Grid.Column="1" 
    Style="{StaticResource MainBorderStyle}">
    <HeaderedContentControl 
              Content="{Binding Path=Workspaces}"
              ContentTemplate="{StaticResource WorkspacesTemplate}"
              Header="Decision Workspaces"
              Style="{StaticResource MainHCCStyle}"/>
</Border>
```

The TabControl is defined in a static resource:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ClosableTabItemTemplate">
    <DockPanel Width="120" ToolTip="{Binding Path=DisplayName, Mode=OneTime}">
        <Button 
    Command="{Binding Path=CloseCommand}"
    Content="X"
    Cursor="Hand"
    DockPanel.Dock="Right"
    Focusable="False"
    FontFamily="Courier" 
    FontSize="9"
    FontWeight="Bold"  
    Margin="0,1,0,0"
    Padding="0"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"
    Width="16" Height="16" 
    />
    <ContentPresenter 
        Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName, Mode=OneTime}"
        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
    />
    </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<!--
This template explains how to render the 'Workspace' content area in the main window.
-->
<DataTemplate x:Key="WorkspacesTemplate">
    <TabControl 
  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
  ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ClosableTabItemTemplate}"
  Margin="4"
  />
</DataTemplate>
```

The Workspaces property which is bound to the HeaderedContentControl's Content property, has a collection of UserControls, which are rendered in the tabs.  This all works fine.

The problem is that when i select a row in a grid in one of the UserControls, switch to a different tab, and then return, the selected row is reset.  The same happens if a RowDetails is open - when I switch away and back to the tab, it is collapsed.

Any way around this?

***Edit***: After looking at the proposed solutions for the TabControl behaviour, I'm wandering if I might ditch it altogether.  Any ideas for a UI that will allow me to keep several relatively complex UserControls and switch between them, not loosing the visuals in the process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common problem with the TabControl. Since it only displays the content of the selected tab. If your tab items are not visuals themselves and are presented with a DataTemplate, then the controls will be created and released as you switch tabs.

There are two solutions to this problem [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/PersistTab.aspx) and [here](http://eric.burke.name/dotnetmania/2009/04/26/22.09.28), which attempt to retain the visuals for each tab.

Comment: I wish I knew this was a 'common' problem...  I guess I will have to look at the attached behaviour solution.  Thanks!